# Where does Mountain Lion's Calendar.app store its preferences?

Tags: macos, calendar, preferences

The program Calendar.app clearly has some preferences that are settable.

[image]

However, when I type `defaults read com.apple.Calendar` (and various permutations on capitalization), I get the message `Domain com.apple.Calendar does not exist`. Additionally, I don't find a file in `~/Library/Preferences` with a time stamp to match the changes I made.

Where does the Mountain Lion Calendar program store its preferences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After performing an extensive search of my user directory I have found file associated with the Calendar.app, if you check the Info.plist contained within in the Calendar.app bundle you will find that the identifier for the Calendar app is still iCal and the file you are looking for is like "com.apple.iCal"

The files I found using the following search is:

```
$ find /Users/yourusername/ -name com.apple.iCal*
```

Files found:

```
/Users/yourusername/Library/Application Support/SyncServices/Local/clientdata/com.apple.iCal
/Users/yourusername/Library/Caches/com.apple.helpd/Generated/com.apple.iCal.help
/Users/yourusername/Library/Caches/com.apple.helpd/SDMHelpData/AppleExtra/English/HelpSDMIndexFile/com.apple.iCal.help
/Users/yourusername/Library/Caches/com.apple.iCal
/Users/yourusername/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.iCal.helper.E4000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.plist
/Users/yourusername/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.iCal.helper.E4000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.plist.lockfile
/Users/yourusername/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iCal.helper.plist
/Users/yourusername/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iCal.helper.plist.lockfile
/Users/yourusername/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iCal.plist
/Users/yourusername/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iCal.plist.lockfile
/Users/yourusername/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.iCal.savedState/
```

Additionally I am Fairly certain that iCal in Mountain Lion is using iCloud to store app preferences, or at least it should be since its suppose to be a cloud heavy app to span the iOS and OS X device boundary. I Will have to check into this further, and see how it works when iCloud is enabled or not...

It should be using iCloud as noted in developer docs topic of [Designing for Key-Value Data in iCloud](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForKey-ValueDataIniCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH7-SW1)

> To store discrete values in iCloud for app preferences, app configuration, or app state, use iCloud key-value storage.

Comment: Is there a way to query said key-value storage from the command line or see what settings an app has stored?

Comment: @Daniel Lawson, Command line access would be hard to do. I would think its something that would require a code signing identifier or something of the like to ID as the App for that iCloud user. Since each iCloud enabled app has storage on the cloud that only it has access to...

Comment: If I change a setting while offline or if I set up an account on my Mac that doesn't have a corresponding iCloud account, the settings still persist, though — so there must be *some* local storage of preferences…

Comment: @DanielLawson have you tried looking in ~/Library/Mobile Documents  it may be putting copies of app settings in there as well http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/answers/how_to_locally_back_up_documents

Comment: If it's in there, I can't find it. But good pointers.

Comment: Also have you checked Lri answer out, its likly that iCal is a code-signed app

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4610/discussion-between-daniel-lawson-and-mrdaniel)

Comment: As a note, I don't think Key Value storage is stored in Mobile Documents, its a different type of Storage.

Answer (score 3):

The bundle identifier is still `com.apple.iCal`. You can see it from the `Info.plist` or with something like `bid() { osascript -e "id of app \"$*\""; }`.

So the property list for the preferences is still in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iCal.plist`. It will be probably be moved to `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iCal/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iCal.plist` if Apple sandboxes Calendar.